# Запрос возвращает номер месяца а надо его наименование

Tags: sql-server

Делаю в sql-serve(transact-sql),на `MONTHNAME` ругается,как можно реализовать по другому?

```
 (select MONTH(CONVERT (date, GETDATE())))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тема закрыта,может кому понадобится

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, @df1) AS [months]
```